# Best way to scan and compare images in real time

Tags: windows, macos, image-processing, scanning

Need your help.
For example i hv game. It is 500x500 pixels. shows random pictures. When there is a particular picture of smiling dog, you need to press space in 1 second.

Lets assume that we allready have that particular image of smiling dog in our memory.(Lets call it target image from now) And all that is left, is just to compare scan image to a target one. So we need to: scan this 500x500 area in real time(one-ten times per second) and compare scan result to target image, and then, do some stuff, depending on a result of comparison.
I need to do it as fast, as reliable and as efficient(in terms of computing power) as possible.

Also i need to be able to move window with game, so it would not brake screen capture(I need screen capture to be anchored to game window, not to whole screen)

So whats your suggestions on handling scanning and comparative phases of this programm in fastest, most reliable and most efficient way possible?

/*
EDIT:I think i need to use OpenCV for screen scan and comparision. But what language would be preferable in terms of speed and efficient computing power distribution? C++ or Python?
*/

Also i need this program to work Windows and Mac OS in future, for now it is just windows.

Ty in advance.

/*
EDIT: What do you guys think of this method : 
let our scan result image be "X", and let our target image(image that we allready have aka "image of smiling dog" and want our X to be identical to this image) be "Y".
First we downscale Y from 500x500 to 50x50, than we dowunscale X from 500x500 to 50x50, then we transfer both images to grey scale. And then run normalize sum of squared differene, or even normalized cross corelation to detect similarities betwen X and Y. What do you think? Will it be faster than my suggestion:

{
downsample captured image to 50x50 pixels. Then compare every 25th pixel one by one, gradually(If 1st pixel is same as in target image - proceed to next pixel. If not - wait untill next scanning event and scann first pixel again) to downsampled target image. If all pixels are identical - then we are good, and we found that exact picture.
}
*/

Comment: And could the smiling dog be a black labrador in a grassy green park or a grey bulldog in a lake? Or do you know it will be a specific photo you can compare with?

Comment: it will be a specific photo that i allready have.

Comment: If you want it cross-platform, maybe consider Python. If you want the image processing reasonably fast, consider OpenCV. You may find a simple average of each of the three colour channels is enough to detect which image is showing.

Comment: Similar is a really broad term. Measuring the similarity between images is a complex topic. Anyhow if you want to compare two pictures of different dogs that just look similar and that should count as match, then a simple pixel by pixel comparison won’t work. Even a simple histogram comparison won’t work.

Comment: How many target images do you have, or expect to have? Can you share some **representative** ones please? Preferably 3 or more.